# Checking if a URL returns a PDF

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I need to check if a URL returns a PDF document using PHP. Right now I'm using the file_get_mimetype function. A normal URL(https://www.google.com/) returns type as application/octet-stream while a normal pdf link (http://www.brainlens.org/content/newsletters/Spring%202013.pdf) returns application/pdf. But now I also encounter URL's like http://www.dadsgarage.com/~/media/Files/example.ashx or http://www.wpdn.org/webfm_send/241 which also is pdf but returns application/octet-stream. There are other URL's too which opens a Save as dialog box which also has to be detected.

Answer (score 8):

Use [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Eg:

```
$url = "http://www.dadsgarage.com/~/media/Files/example.ashx";
if (in_array("Content-Type: application/pdf", get_headers($url))) {
    echo "URL returns PDF";
}

print_r(get_headers($url));
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=604800
    [2] => Content-Length: 194007
    [3] => Content-Type: application/pdf
    [4] => Expires: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 09:40:20 GMT
    [5] => Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 16:46:30 GMT
    [6] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [7] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    [8] => Content-Disposition: inline; filename="example.pdf"
    [9] => X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    [10] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    [11] => X-Provider: AWS
    [12] => Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 09:40:20 GMT
    [13] => Connection: close
)
```

Answer (score 1):

mime types could include:

```
application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf
```

Comment: Yeah, But the links that I have provided returns application/octet-stream not any of those..

Comment: then what is your question?

Comment: http://www.wpdn.org/webfm_send/241  this URL is a pdf. But file_get_mimetype returns application/octet-stream. I want to detect that as pdf